# Find the maximum and minimum of Cov(X,Y)

Tags: probability

How to show that for $U∼Unif(0,1)$,

(1) $max$ $Cov(X,Y)=Cov(F^{-1}(U),G^{-1}(U))$ and

(2) $min$ $Cov(X,Y)=Cov(F^{-1}(U),G^{-1}(1-U))$

where $F(a)=P(X\leq\ a)$ and $G(a)=P(Y \leq\ a)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are positive random variables.

Comment: I believe you omitted saying that $U \sim Unif(0,1).$ A fundamental result, often used in simulation, is that $F_X^{-1}(U)$ has the same distribution as $X$. Sometimes the inverse CDF is called the 'quantile' function.

Comment: Yes, $ U∼Unif(0,1)$. Can you be more specific on this question?

Comment: Maybe see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give more hints on the posted problem?